# I have require new chart. I writing with highchart but i don't see this is chart. Please help me?

Tags: d3.js, charts, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk7Dm.png)
this is the image chart I need.
I have required a new chart. I writing with a highchart but I don't see this is a chart. Please help me?[The combined chart between xrange chart and line chart. When clicking on the point line chart, it shows the line to be visible for both charts. When hovering over the point line chart, the tooltip is displayed as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk7Dm.png)

[when hover show tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89P3X.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `line` and `xrange` series with separate y-axis, but common x-axis.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: [{
        height: '50%'
    }, {
        offset: 0,
        top: '50%',
        height: '50%',
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            distance: 0,
            x: 0,
            y: -15
        }
    }],
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [...]
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
        type: 'xrange',
        data: [...]
    }],
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g1fbLcpw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/x-range-series

Comment: thank you. but I have some feature. I updated on img. Please help me. Thanks you!

Comment: 1. You can use `crosshair `from Highstock: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.crosshair, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zonqhxag/ 2. It requires custom code, you can for example reduce chart container height by CSS to hide the part with xrange series.

Comment: Well, I understand what you mean, you can tell me how to add point hover over the point at the end of each process of the xrange chart. Thank you for supporting me. I see you as a good person. Can I make facebook friends with you?

Comment: Hi @Ngọc Thịnh, You can use `scatter` series to achieve the result, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/arkcs68j/

Comment: It's correct. Thank you. but i can't customize it to be rectangular. Can you help me how to customize when hovering on the line chart then show the information on the tooltip of the series line chart, similar to xrange chart and scatter only show name series of it. same image. This is my chart https://jsfiddle.net/Lk9xnewf/11/. this is my facebook: https://www.facebook.com/ngocthinh.ngocthinh/. If you can, please make friends with me. Thank you!

Comment: 1. You need to define your own symbol for rect: https://jsfiddle.net/ra21nwyj/ 2. Shared tooltip seems to be enough: https://jsfiddle.net/aetspyr0/